# TFS Git | Multiple git repositories under one root folder

Tags: git, github, tfs

Is it possible to create multiple GIT repositories under parent TFS root folder. For example if I have a folder structure are below:

- FOLDER-1

  - Comp -1

    - Repo-1
  - Comp -2

    - Repo-2

in the above folder structure I have parent TFS folder **FOLDER-1** , the parent folder have multiple compartments/folders like **COMP-1** and **COMP-2** and within  **COMP-1** and **COMP-2**  I want to have git repositories to be created.
Wanted to know, if this is possible in TFS-Git?
I understand is very different from the GitHub flat structure.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. There is no "root folder". There is a team project. That team project can contain repositories. Repositories have no hierarchy, unless you use submodules. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielMann There are multiple projects for me. I just want group it under one project for easy separation of concerns